# How do I define permitted arrow directions for my instance of SexyTooltip?

Tags: ios, objective-c, typedef, nsenumerator

According to the documentation [here](https://github.com/calm/SexyTooltip) I am to specify an array of my arrow directions for SexyTooltip using a `typedef`.

They suggest:

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSUInteger, SexyTooltipArrowDirection) {
    SexyTooltipArrowDirectionUp,
    SexyTooltipArrowDirectionDown,
    SexyTooltipArrowDirectionLeft,
    SexyTooltipArrowDirectionRight
};
```

I'm confused about what a `typedef` is and how I would use it after I define it. How would I implement this as described in the documentation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an example in the `SexyTooltip.h`:

```
SexyTooltip *tooltip = [[SexyTooltip alloc] initWithView:self.instructionsView];
tooltip.permittedArrowDirections = @[@(SexyTooltipArrowDirectionDown), @(SexyTooltipArrowDirectionUp)];
```

You do not create the enum shown in your question, that is already provided for you.